# Html - how to actually work with local iframes? (Nothing shows up)

Tags: html, iframe

I am doing some work that would require me building up html inside of embedded iframes. Sort of like jsbin does.

However I'm stumped with my very first spike.

How come my html isn't being rendered when I put it inside an iframe?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe>
    <html>
      <head><meta charset=utf-8 /></head>
      <body>
        <h1>Big Header</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
  </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here's my jsbin.](http://jsbin.com/omumaf/1/)

Additionally when I tried drawing some svgs inside the iframe with d3 they came out looking all weird and not scaling. After opening dev tools and editing the svg text as html I found that even adding a non-meaningful space anywhere would get it to redraw and render correctly. So bonus points if anyone can tell me any resources I can read up on cause clearly iframes don't work like I thought.

Answer (score 1):

iframes need to be pointed at a page to load. you don't put html between iframe tags. if you put anything between iframe tags - it is text you want to display in the case the browser the client is using doesn't support the  tag. you should make the html above its own local html page, and point the iframe src attribute above to point at that web page.

Comment: This is simply not true. Look at the jsbin output pane, they do not have an src and, while the do POST a save they build up your html on the client.

Comment: they're probably using javascript to rip the src attribute out as the page loads so people can't figure out where files are located. i've seen ad services do that before.

Comment: If that was true you would be able to see the network activity in chrome's network tab. Their source is open on github and while I don't quite understand what is going on, it's not a GET request. They actually grab the iframe's contentDocument property and seem to be modifying it.

Comment: As a followup I pinged remy (from jsbin) on twitter asking for hints, he directed me to this video confirming what I said: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4lBEZTThvg

Answer (score 0):

After a day of research:

Like Mike said, html inside an iframe is for the case the browser does not support iframes and will not show up otherwise.  However, it IS absolutely possible to construct a document inside an iframe on the fly and without a server-side query.  To do this, you have to use javascript to construct the document. You can get a reference to it and write html like so:

```
var  iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    ,doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document
    ; 
doc.open();
doc.write('<p>Some html</p>');
do.close();
```

Note that as Remy mentions [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4lBEZTThvg) the document must be opened before writing and closed after.